# Symfony: Variable "user" does not exist

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I get the variable does not exist error everytime I try to access a site on my blog.

the **twig** template:

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title text-center">All Users</h3>
  </div>
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Email Address</th>
        <th>Password</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for user in userlist %}
          <tr>
              <td>{{ user.username }}</td>
              <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
              <td>{{ user.password }}</td>
          </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn btn-info">
<a href="{{ path('edit', {'id':user.id}) }}" style="color: #FEFEFE">Edit profile</a>
</button>
{% endblock %}
```

the Controller :

```
<?php
// src/BlogBundle/Controller/UserController.php

namespace BlogBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security;
use BlogBundle\Entity\Blog;
use BlogBundle\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

    class UserController extends Controller
    {
    /**
      *@Security("has_role('ROLE_ADMIN')")
      * @Route("/users", name="users", requirements={"page": "\d+"})
     */

        public function listAction()
        {
            $user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('BlogBundle:User')->findBy(array(), array('username' => 'DESC'));
            dump($user);
             return $this->render('BlogBundle:user:userlist.html.twig', [
               'userlist' => $user
             ]);
        }
        /**
      * @Route("/users/edit/{id}", name="edit", requirements={"id" = "\d+"}, defaults={"id" = 0})
      *@Security("has_role('ROLE_ADMIN')")
      */
      public function editAction(Request $request, User $user) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $user = $em->getRepository('BlogBundle:User')->find($username);
        $form->handleRequest($request);


        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

          $em->persist($user);
          $em->flush();

          return $this->render('BlogBundle:user:userlist.html.twig', array(
            'user' => $user,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'success' => true
          ));
        }

        return $this->render('FOSUserBundle:Profile:edit.html.twig');
      }
      public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
          'data_class' => 'BlogBundle\Entity\User'
        ]);
      }

    }
    ?>
```

and finally the User Entity:

```
<?php
// src/BlogBundle/Entity/User.php

namespace BlogBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

    }
    /**
     * Get the value of Id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getId() {
      return $this->id;
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is, create a page that only the admin can access which displays a list of all users from my doctrine database. --> listAction()
next to that I would like to have the possibility to edit all the users information --> editAction()
any ideas?
the error occurs in the twig template line: "{{ path('edit', {'id':user.id}) }} ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put the button outside your loop, so yes, the variable user doesn't exist, simply put put

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn btn-info">
<a href="{{ path('edit', {'id':user.id}) }}" style="color: #FEFEFE">Edit profile</a>
</button>
```

in the for loop

Comment: Thanks! Totally oversaw that!

Comment: you welcome. don't forget to pass the answer as resolved